# Busca por endereços próximos a um determinado CEP

Tags: javascript, maps, geolocalização, cep

Estou implementando um sistema como um delivery online, o cliente entrará na ferramenta e colocará seu CEP, com isso o sistema deverá informar todos os restaurantes/empresas, próximas a ele.

Queria saber se alguém tem uma solução boa, para realizar essa busca.

Minha ideia principal era, salvar no banco de dados todas as empresas, com seus CEPS e o raio máximo de entrega, quando o cliente fizesse a busca com seu CEP, iria trazer todas as empresas do banco e depois para cada empresa eu usaria um WebService que me retorna a distancia entre os CEPS. Porem essa solução não me parece nada eficiente.

Alguém saberia alguma forma de implementar isso?